# Can we adjust the order of workspace subtabs?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

Working with a Lightning console app and we want to be able to have subtabs opened next to the one from which they originated regardless of when they were opened so:

```
 Tab 1 | Tab 1a | Tab 1b | Tab 2 | Tab 2a | Tab 2b |
```

Instead of chronological order like:

```
 Tab 1 | Tab 2 | Tab 1a | Tab 2a | Tab 2b | Tab 1b |
```

I've looked through the methods for workspace tabs as well as gone into the setup section for the lightning experience but haven't found anything so far that controls the order of tabs or subtabs. So is this at all possible? Thank you.

Cross posted in the developers forum.

Comment: What does Tab 1a represent, a child or relation of Tab 1?

Comment: sorry forgot how small comments are, yes each lettered tab was opened from either 1 or 2